# Authorization bearer is undefined in JWT

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, token

```js
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const password = req.body.password
  const user = { name: password }
  jwt.sign({ user }, "secretkey", (err, token) => {
      console.log(token)
  });
});

app.get("/", verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  jwt.verify(req.token, "secretkey", (err, authData) => {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(403);
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.render("index", { title: "home-page", urls: result })
      console.log(authData);
    }
  });
});

// Verify Token
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  if (typeof bearerHeader !== "undefined") {
    const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
    const bearerToken = bearer[1];
    req.token = bearerToken;
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
    console.log(bearerHeader)
  }
}
```

I want to make a verification function(middle ware) for my routes using JWT. But the bearerHeader is undefined so it redirects me to the login page after I type the correct password

Comment: Do you have front-end code for this?

Comment: yes here you go *<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label class="white" for="password">password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>
</form> *

Comment: `console.log(token)` wont magically set it into a header

Comment: the sign method wont do it? if not then how to do it?

Comment: set it into a secure http only cookie anything else is doing it wrong and insecure, using a header implies your need to set it into the client when sending the request which means you need to store it somewhere like localstorage which is insecure

Comment: so thats what causes the problem?